# Android application crashes by manipulating with canvas. Cordova 2.0.0/2.1.0

Tags: cordova

My application uses cordova (v 2.1.0) to shoot pictures using tablet's cam and render them to a canvas. I use my own functions to move and zoom in/out this image in javascript.
My application reboots after several zoom or move operations. Crash report from LogCat is below.

```
DEBUG/CordovaWebView(4897): >>> loadUrlNow()
DEBUG/DroidGap(4897): onMessage(onNativeReady,null)
DEBUG/DroidGap(4897): onMessage(onPageFinished,file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
DEBUG/chromium(4897): Unknown chromium error: -400
DEBUG/DroidGap(4897): onMessage(spinner,stop)
DEBUG/CordovaLog(4897): JSCallback Error: Request failed with status 0
DEBUG/CordovaLog(4897): file:///android_asset/www/js/cordova-2.1.0.js: Line 3743 : JSCallback Error: Request failed with status 0
INFO/Web Console(4897): JSCallback Error: Request failed with status 0 at file:///android_asset/www/js/cordova-2.1.0.js:3743
DEBUG/JsMessageQueue(4897): Set native->JS mode to 0
DEBUG/dalvikvm(2586): GC_CONCURRENT freed 431K, 8% free 9225K/9927K, paused 3ms+1ms
DEBUG/Beautiful Widgets(4120000)(4940): WidgetRefreshService
```

When I move or zoom canvas no Cordova API functions is being invoking. Than why my app crashes?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved by replacing links with span tags. My guess is that cordova captures all clicks/touchstarts on links dispite click event have been catched. Then cordova sends request to its local webserver. If requests are frequent cordova fails.